# Get the value in an input text box, the id from side server

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery

friends.

I have the following input, the value comes from the server side in this case is "Y", the idea is that the checkbox changes to checked when it is "Y", but the script is not working for me.

Thanks

`<input type="checkbox" name="choice-animals" id="choice">`

```
var variable = $('#choice').val();
       console.log("----+++" + variable);

       $(document).ready(function () {
           $('input[id="choice"]').each(function (index) {
             
               


               if ($(this).val()=="Y")
                   ($(this).prop('checked', true));
               else
                   ($(this).prop('checked', false));

           });
       });
```

[Console.log return on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqFwS.png)

Comment: Please post your code here as text and provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Couple things to fix in your code:

1. If you happen to have multiple checkboxes, make sure that they have unique index. In HTML syntax one id-attribute value should appear only once on that page, so it shouldn't be used to select multiple elements, for that class, or data-attribute is way better. I provided alternative code to select all checkboxes-
2. To check that input actually has .val(), it needs to have value-attribute.
3. If else syntax uses () for condition and your code should be inside of {}

```js
var options = $('input[type="checkbox"]')

options.each(function(e){
  if($(this).val() === "Y") {
    $(this).prop('checked', true)        
  } else {
    $(this).prop('checked', false)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>
  Choice 1
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice-animals" value="Y">
</label>

<label>
  Choice 2
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice-animals" value="X">
</label>
```